# Pandas df.plot() KeyError Thrown

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

BIG EDIT: **This error will not throw if I remove index_col = 1 from the read_csv function. Leaving this question up because I am curious why this happens.**

I have the following CSV:

```
Agency  Division                   Expenditures ($000,000)
NYPD    OPERATIONS                 3331
NYPD    EXECUTIVE MANAGEMENT       489.4
NYPD    SCHOOL SAFETY              279.6
NYPD    ADMINISTRATION-PERSONNEL   263.9
```

When I plot this with:

```
data.plot(x='Division',y='Expenditures ($000,000)')
```

I am thrown:

```
KeyError: 'Division'
```

I am confused because my index is named 'Division' so why would I be thrown this error? Using data.plot(kind='bar') gives me a reasonable plot, but I am having an issue calling this column by its key.

Full code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

NYPD_data = "D:/CSVs/NYPD_Spending.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(NYPD_data, index_col = 1)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.xlabel('NYPD Division')
data.plot(x='Division', y='Expenditures ($000,000)')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'Agency': {0: 'NYPD', 1: 'NYPD', 2: 'NYPD', 3: 'NYPD'},
        'Division': {0: 'OPERATIONS',
                     1: 'EXECUTIVE MANAGEMENT',
                     2: 'SCHOOL SAFETY',
                     3: 'ADMINISTRATION-PERSONNEL'},
        'Expenditures ($000,000)': {0: 3331.0, 1: 489.4, 2: 279.6, 3: 263.9}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.plot(df['Division'], df['Expenditures ($000,000)'])
plt.xticks(rotation='30')
plt.xlabel('NYPD Division')
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Produces Plot:**

```
df.plot('Division', 'Expenditures ($000,000)')
df.plot(x='Division', y='Expenditures ($000,000)')
```

**Does not work:**

```
df.plot(x=df['Division'], y=['Expenditures ($000,000)'])
```

This doesn't work because the source is already specified by `df.plot`.  `x` & `y` should be `x : label or position, default None` and `y : label, position or list of label, positions, default None` respectively.  So the issue is sending parameters to the method in an incorrect form. [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

[DataFrame Plotting API](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#api-dataframe-plotting)

**In the case of:**

```
df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', index_col=1)

df = 
                          Agency    Expenditures ($000,000)
Division        
OPERATIONS                  NYPD                     3331.0
EXECUTIVE MANAGEMENT        NYPD                      489.4
SCHOOL SAFETY               NYPD                      279.6
ADMINISTRATION-PERSONNEL    NYPD                      263.9
```

Note that `Division` is now the index and no longer a column so using `x = 'Division'` will not work.

```
df.plot()
```

[image]